# Install Remix Os to SSD drive using dd

Tags: dd, chromebook, android-x86

I have successfully unlocked my Baytrail chromebook and I am able to run Remix Os from an USB stick.

Now I would like to install it as the default operating system on the SSD. Knowing that Remix Os for PC does not provide any installer for Linux but can be installed from Windows. Also knowing that it is possible to install it to an usb drive using dd, is it possible to install to the SSD using dd ?